# Question about best practices and Macros from the book 'C++ Coding Standards'

Tags: c++, macros, coding-style

From Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu's 'C++ Coding Standards', Item 16: Avoid Macros under Exceptions for this guideline they wrote:

> For conditional compilation (e.g.,
>   system-dependent parts), avoid
>   littering your code with #ifdefs.
>   Instead, prefer to organize code such
>   that the use of macros drives
>   alternative implementations of one
>   common interface, and then use the
>   interface throughout.

I'm having trouble understanding exactly what they mean by this. How can you drive alternate implementations without the use of #ifdef conditional compile macro directives? Can someone provide an example to help illustrate what's being proposed by the above paragraph?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What they mean is that you should abstract your code from the system-dependent part through the use of abstract base classes and use condition compilation only at the point of instantiation.

```
class SystemAgnosticInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~SystemAgnosticInterface() {}
    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};
```

You could then for example have a Windows and a Linux specific implementations of the interface (each of which you will only be included in the compilation for its associated platform), use such as :

```
SystemAgnosticInterface *createFoo()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    return new WindowsImplementation;
#else
    return new LinuxImplementation;
#endif
}

int main()
{
    SystemAgnosticInterface *foo = createFoo();
    foo->doStuff(); // No conditional compilation here
    delete foo;
}
```

This is obviously an over-simplified code sample, but I hope you'll understand the point : it's not about avoiding `#ifdef` completely, just that they should not clutter every part of your code.

Comment: Although the interface doesn't have to be virtual - you could instead have an `#ifdef` ed typedef, to different classes on each system which all implement a common API.

Answer (score 2):

For non-member functions:

```
//implementation!

#ifdef _WIN32
    void EatWindow(Food &) {}
    void DrinkWindow(Beverage &) {}
    void SleepWindow(Bed &) {}
#else
    void EatLinux(Food &) {}
    void DrinkLinux(Beverage &) {}
    void SleepLinux(Bed &) {}
#endif

//interface

#ifdef _WIN32
    #define Eat(food)       EatWindow(food)
    #define Drink(beverage) DrinkWindow(beverage)
    #define Sleep(bed)      SleepWindow(bed)
#else
    #define Eat(food)       EatLinux(food)
    #define Drink(beverage) DrinkLinux(beverage)
    #define Sleep(bed)      SleepLinux(bed)
#endif
```

Use the *interfaces* `Eat()`, `Drink()` and `Sleep()` throughout your program, be it windows or linux. No conditional check anywhere else!

Comment: For the interface the syntax seems a bit off. Did you mean to use #define for Eat(), Drink(), Sleep()? Or perhaps you meant to include curly braces.